# Text read from disk does not comply with new line character

Tags: dart, flutter

Using the Text widget with text that's read from disk, that contains new line characters \n, does not go to new line. Anyone have suggestions of how I can get around this? The text in the file is [image]

The code for the image you see above is as follows:

```
Text(valueFromFile, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red))
```

My text is being read from an Xml file that is contained in my assets folder.

Comment: Does your file contain actual '\n' characters? If so then that's not a new line character, that's two characters '\' (backslash) and 'n' (well, lowercase n letter).

Comment: @uaraven yes it does contain those letters. I just thought of the solution, thanks for your comment. It helped me think of it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment from uaraven above

> Does your file contain actual '\n' characters? If so then that's not a new line character ...

Helped me come up with a solution. Since the Text Widget is interpreting the \n characters as normal characters, I just did a replace on it and inserted the actual escape character.

```
var correctlyEscapedString = valueFromFile.replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
Text(correctlyEscapedString, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String someText = 
"This is your line number one\n\n"
"This is your line number two\n\n"
"This is your line number three\n\n"
"This is your line number four\n\n"
"This is your line number five\n\n";
```

this is one option for you.

```
int maxLines
final
```

> An optional maximum number of lines for the text to span, wrapping if
>   necessary. If the text exceeds the given number of lines, it will be
>   truncated according to overflow.
>
> If this is 1, text will not wrap. Otherwise, text will be wrapped at
>   the edge of the box.
>
> If this is non-null, it will override even explicit null values of
>   Text.maxLines.

Comment: I don't see how this would help. The problem is not that it's wrapping, it's visually displaying the \n in the UI. It doesn't understand the \n. My text view grows with the text it's not set to a fixed size so wrapping is not the problem. It should still be going to a new line.

Comment: then i will suggest you to take another text.

Comment: Hahaha, I can't just change the text that a client wants in their app. But thank you for the suggestion, I just thought of a solution.