# Flutter creating new line doesn't work when i read text from asset

Tags: flutter, dart

In our application we have some data as text which them stored into `assets` folder inside `lib` directory, as we know `\n` can create new line between text and we can ever use into `Text` widget, for example

```dart
Text('Hello \n World),
```

result:

```
Hello
World
```

whats my issue?

as i said we stored texts into files and when i try to read them line by line with this code:

```dart
  Future<Sampletext> _resolveTexts() async {
    final List<String> lines= [];

    await rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/sample.txt')
        .asStream()
        .transform(const LineSplitter())
        .forEach((element) {
      lines.add(element);
    });

    /*...*/
  }
```

`\n` couldn't create new line and its also is into texts, for example:

```dart
Text(lines[0]),
```

result:

```
Hello \n World
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text read from disk does not comply with new line character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577190/text-read-from-disk-does-not-comply-with-new-line-character)

Comment: @Spatz no it doesn't my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your assets have this:

```dart
Hello World
Hello \n World
Hello World
```

When you read it line by line, you will got:

```dart
strings = ['Hello World','Hello \n World','Hello World'];
```

So why?
Because the `\n` you saw is string, the value in your memory is '\\n'.
The real '\n' is

```dart
Hello World\n
Hello \\n World\n
Hello World
```

You need to replace `\\n` to `\n` before readLine, so that you can really make

```dart
Hello \n World
```

into

```dart
Hello 
World
```

You can make some change

```dart
await rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/sample.txt')
        .asStream()
        .transform(const LineSplitter())
        .forEach((element) {
      lines.add(element.replaceAll('\\n', '\n'));
    });
```

Comment: first of all i must replace all `\n` to `\\n` in text file?

Comment: No you needn't. The real line break `\n` already read as new line, but the text '\n' (which `\\n` in memory) you need to replace to the real  line break '\n'. So that you can got what you want.

Comment: i fixed your code problem and solved my issue

Comment: So `lines.add(element.replaceAll('\\n', '\n'))` can add two lines? Thanks!

Comment: separating `replaceAll` in new line? like with you last updated answer? it doesn't work and i getting error